# Getting selected model in angular select directive

Tags: angularjs, directive

I've created a directive to display dropdowns (form selects).
However I cannot find a way to mark the selected option.

html form

```
 <div content-selects ng-model="ctrl.contentSelects.riskStatus" selection="oneWMS.riskStatusId"></div> <!-- oneWMS.riskStatusId -->
```

directive

```
function contentSelects(){
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        templateUrl: '/app/Directives/contentSelects.tpl.html',
        replace:true,
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',
            selection: '='
        },
        controller:function($scope){

        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.selectedModel = scope.ngModel[attrs.selection];

            scope.isChanged = function () {
                //console.log("changed");
            }

            element.removeAttr('id');

        }
    };
}// end function contentSelects
```

This is where I don't understand: the directive template

```
<div class="input-group">
<select id="{{id}}">
<option value="model.refId" ng-repeat="model in ngModel track by model.refId" ng-model="ngModel[selection]" >{{model.value}} *** {{selection}} *** {{ngModel[selection]}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

In the actual value, `{{ngModel[selection]}}` gives me exactly what I want (the target model row), but when tied to ng-model it doesn't retrieve anything :/

```
ng-model="ngModel[selection]"
```

What is wrong with it? Using curly brackets break it of course...

Comment: Can you put your code in Plunkr?

Comment: Show a sample of your data. Did you try the `<select>` outside of a directive? You should also know that you are effectively creating a custom input control (that just happen to use `<select>` under the covers), and so you should `require: "ngModel"` rather than bind to it via scope. See more about creating [custom input controls](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)

Comment: Here's my Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/Na0JmaGZQDPtw6SeBDd4

Comment: you really should use `ng-options` rather than `ng-repeat` in a `<select>` element.  aside from that, the posted answer is correct, your `ng-model` is inside `<options>` when it should be inside `<select>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is because of ngModel included in option element. You should move it to select element.

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xgEnY7xMkcgd7WJF4K2c?p=preview)

```
<div class="input-group">
  <select ng-model="selectedModel" >
    <option ng-value="model" ng-repeat="model in ngModel">{{model}}         
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And also look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: It's a great answer, I've tried and apply it to my Plunkr but it's still the same outcome. Can you see why? http://plnkr.co/edit/YUdXrRO0lhzxp7kIlTbs

Comment: Use ng-options because this way is not supported by angular 1.4. I have used angular 1.2.

Comment: in my application, `scope.selectedModel = scope.ngModel[scope.selection];
            console.log(scope.selectedModel);` comes out as undefined. That's because `scope.selection` is undefined. However it does have a value of 2!

Comment: using ng-options now, it's better but still hasn't solved my issue see above

Comment: It works fine console.log(scope.selectedModel). http://postimg.org/image/c2t9pec4t/

Comment: I know I really don't get why it works on plunker and not on my application.

Comment: if I hard code  `selection="2"` in the html it works. if I go `selection="riskStatusId"` it is undefined. But on the next line I go {{riskStatusId}} and it echoes 2...